# LinearLayout with style and without orientation issue?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-styles

I have style for `LinearLayout`:

```
<style name="clickable_zone">
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:id">@+id/click_zone</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/simple_button_holo</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
</style>
```

I use this style at different layouts as:

```
<LinearLayout
        style="@style/clickable_zone" />
```

But in this case I get warning about orientation issue. Of course, I can disable this warning. But, can I resolve my problem, without disabling the warning?

UPD1. Issue message:

```
Checks that LinearLayouts with multiple children set the orientation

The default orientation of a LinearLayout is horizontal. It's pretty easy to believe that the layout is vertical, add multiple children to it, and wonder why only the first child is visible (when the subsequent children are off screen to the right). This lint rule helps pinpoint this issue by warning whenever a LinearLayout is used with an implicit orientation and multiple children.

It also checks for empty LinearLayouts without an orientation attribute that also defines an id attribute. This catches the scenarios where children will be added to the LinearLayout dynamically.
```

Comment: Can't you just leave out the orientation in your style.xml?

Comment: Ofcouse can, but this is as disable warning...

Comment: I wouldn't know how to solve this, if I add your custom style and add it to a linear layout I don't get any warnings... Can you give some more information? What does the warning say?

Comment: @Kevin, see UPD1 (first post). Сurious, I was wrong and disable this issue for whole eclipse (not only file or project). And now don't know how to reset this warning...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is somewhere in preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

Comment: @MrsEd, `This edit did not correct critical issues with the post ` - Did I miss something or did you just add a tag you like and called that `critical issue`? Anyway for those minor edits I consider it very rude to reject-edit. There is an approve-edit mechanism for that.

Comment: The message is self-explanatory IMO.